# Is it possible to use a variable to change text inside a variable in batch?

Tags: batch-file, variables

I'm trying to make a variable that I can call upon to do set /p variable=enter:
However I would also like to be able to change the variable to make it multi-purpose, here is what I have so far:

```
set enter=set /p %secvar%=Enter:

:new
set secvar=name
cls
echo what is your name
%enter%
goto name
```

This doesn't work and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, how do I make this work or is what I'm doing naïve?

Comment: Move `set secvar=name` up to before your first line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
@echo off
setlocal
call :enter #one "Your value for '#one' ? "
call :enter #two "Your value for '#two' ? " "default for #2"
call :enter #three "Your value for '#three' ? " defaultfor#3
call :enter #four "" "default for #4"
call :enter #five "" defaultfor#5
call :enter #six "Your value for '#six' ? "
call :enter #seven 
call :enter #eight "" defaultfor#8
call :enter #nine "" "default for #9"
set #
goto :eof

:enter
set "%1=%~3"
if "%~2"=="" (set /p "%1=Please enter value for %1 ? "
 ) else (set /p "%1=%~2")
goto :eof
```

The routine `:enter` accepts 1 to 3 parameters. The first is a variable-name to set, the second is optional - the prompt message. The third parameter is also optional, specifying the value to use if the response is just <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The second and third parameters may be quoted strings or a single string of characters. The second parameter must be `""` for no prompt but set a default  value.

Run the demonstration and reply 1..9 in sequence. This will show the values assigned. Run again but just reply <kbd>Enter</kbd> to the prompt; the result will be that those variables with a default value will be set to that default, those without will be "set" to *nothing* (ie. will be deleted from the environment if they existed)

Comment: Sorry, I need more information on what's going on here. Such as what the "set #" is doing and the :enter routine. What does set "%1=%~3" do?

Comment: `set #` lists the variables currently set in the environment whose names start `#`. `set "%1=%~3"` sets the value of the variable (first parameter to the routine = `%1`) to the value (third parameter to the routine = `%3`). The tilde (`~``) removes any enclosing quotes from the parameter. So `call :enter #two "Your value for '#two' ? " "default for #2"` has first parameter `#two`, second `"Your value for '#two' ? "` and third `"default for #2"` so `set "%1=%~3"` sets the value of the variable `#two` to the value `"default for #2"`  minus the enclosing quotes =`default for #2"

Comment: And `if "%~2"==""` takes the second parameter, removes enclosing quotes and then re-encloses the result string in quotes and compares that with an empty string enclosed in quotes. This checks whether  the second parameter is missing or `""` and hence uses the default prompt or the customised prompt supplied as the second parameter.